# TFS notifications without emails

Tags: tfs

In Team Foundation Server, how can one access their notifications through the UI without having to get them through email? I.e., kind-of like GitHub's `/notifications` page.

TFS version: 16.131.27701.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TFS notifications without emails

Sorry for any inconvenience.

I am afraid there is no such out-of-the-box way to access notifications through the UI instead of email.

At this moment, there is only an extensible plugin for Team Foundation Server that sends notifications to **Slack** not for the web UI:

[TfsNotificationRelay](https://github.com/kria/TfsNotificationRelay)

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

Hope this helps.